# I was installing Arch Linux but I messed up, I wanted to restart so I rebooted and booted back into my bootable USB. I am now in the interactive shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, arch-linux

Like I mentioned in the title I was at point where I was about to install grub but I found out I had messed up so I restarted and booted back into my USB, I am now stuck in the interactive shell. I am going to try to reboot and boot into manjaro using anothet USB unless someone says I shouldn't.

Here's a picture of my situation https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA9gu.jpg

Comment: What's your [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? I don't think anybody will stop you from using Manjaro instead of Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't chosen Arch Linux on the boot menu